# Can we reduce the rep needed for closing/migrating questions?

Tags: support, reputation

Now we are out of beta, I have lost my closing privileges because I haven't quite reached 3,000 points. Unfortunately, this means there aren't many people with that privilege - only 4 people are over 3,000 (plus mods) but I haven't seen artlung or Tim Post around for a while.

Maybe we could reduce this back for another month or so perhaps?

Comment: Tim Post was last seen 16 hours ago, so he is around...

Comment: @Farseeker: fair enough...I was going by the last time they posted questions or answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a site needs interim reputation levels, that is a strong indication that the site probably wasn't *really* ready for full status. The question and user counts look good, but users are not voting enough (an *important* part of participation). You're essentially saying that the site does not have the reputation/experience necessary to take care of itself, yet.

The solution is *not* to create another set of interim reputation levels:

> [@rchern](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67054/can-we-grandfather-in-rep-abilities-as-sites-leave-beta/67057#67057): …it would just be yet another beta stage on top of the private and public betas. We don’t need 4 beta stages. **If the site is going to graduate, it needs to graduate.** Perhaps basing graduation off of number of users at the different rep levels instead of a hard 90 days would be a better indication of a community’s ability to self-police and readiness to be a real site.

I agree. We are taking a closer look at this. Having enough users to properly operate the site is a better measurement of readiness, rather than imposing the hard 90-day limit.

Comment: Yes, we discussed this on our meta (link in the link Robert linked - that's a lot of link!!) and I also [posted](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/710/what-does-voting-mean-and-why-is-it-important) encouraging our community to vote.

Comment: What are the "graduate" levels based on?  The current values for the main SO site? Or are they arbitrary?  The current values certainly aren't appropriate for our user base, so if that means not graduating for a while then I'm in favour of it.  It could just be that the level of questions isn't high enough for users to generate the rep they need yet, though I have to say my rep has flat-lined a bit recently because of external commitments.

Comment: @JasonBirch: Nothing like "SO levels." Whatever *feels* right for a site to manage itself. It doesn't take many but I'm going to be researching an actual number. I don't want the number to be unobtainable; just enough to make sure the site works right.

Comment: yes I see your (and rchem's) point. I guess the real solution is to encourage more visitors to the site, and get them voting. Hopefully with PW on Stack Overflow's new question migration tool we'll be seeing a little more activity.

Comment: That seems to be the case.